# file upload from local machine on local machine

Tags: javascript, file-transfer

Is it possible to upload a file from a local machine to the same local machine using JavaScript and/or server technology? The scenario was I had to get a image file from local , do manipulations/ cropping and then save it on that local machine. my website is hosted in another country.

Comment: OK, as of your request: **yes/no**

Comment: @jjpd to me, I do not fully understand your question. Seems like others do, though, so it is definitely my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to upload the file to your server, using a normal file upload. After you have performed the manipulations you would provide a link for the user to download the file.

You cannot force the download back to local storage, the user has to accept the download.

Comment: "using a normal file upload." means on local machine? well my boss calls it upload. but i don't think we can upload a file on local machine path like c:\\uploads\\blabla.

Comment: @jjpd - you can only upload the file from the local machine to your webserver. There is no way to force it back down to the local machine or to perform the upload from the local machine to another location on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ImageMagick on the file itself, most hosting servers support it.
Maybe this helps:
http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/01/22/crop-resize-with-javascript-php-and-imagemagick/

Comment: You mean... force a file to the user machine from your server?

Comment: This is not possible without re-configuring every client computer and respective browser :| You can configure IE (for example) to auto-download some sort of files. But let's say you have 50 clients... this is not a good solution. Why do you need to force it anyway? why not having it sent by mail? some link on the page? etc? IF this would work without user intervention... we'll be doomed to trojans and virus :)